# Python yield keyword significance and confusion about generators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

I am confused why didnt we say `yield b` and what will the differenccce be if i removed `yield a`?

I am just confused on how they compare to a normal function?

```
def fibonacci(n):
    """ A generator for creating the Fibonacci numbers """
    a, b, counter = 0, 1, 0
    while True:
        if (counter > n): 
            return
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
        counter += 1
f = fibonacci(5)
for x in f:
    print(x, " ", end="") # 
print()
```

Comment: Looks like `a` contains the "current" number in the sequence and `b` contains the "next" number.

Comment: You *could* say `yield b`; it is a value that your function will eventually want to yield.  However, if you did that, you would have to somehow skip the `yield a` on the next iteration, since that's the same value as `b` on the current iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal function would look nearly the same:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    """ A function for creating the Fibonacci numbers """
    a, b, counter = 0, 1, 0
    numbers = []
    while True:
        if (counter > n): 
            return numbers
        numbers.append(a)
        a, b = b, a + b
        counter += 1
```

`b` is only used to track the internal state of the process. `a` is the only value ever directly exposed via the iterator or the return value, and `b` is only used to compute `a`.

The regular function computes *all* the requested Fibonacci numbers, then stores them in a list and returns that list to the caller. This may require significant time and memory if `n` is large.

The generator function, on the other hand, returns almost immediately, because it hasn't computed anything yet. It has only returned a `generator` instance, which will, when passed to `next`, compute the next Fibonacci number in the sequence and return it, then go back to waiting until you call `next` again. It only ever uses a small, constant amount of memory, and each call to `next` only takes as much time as is needed to perform a handful of additions.

Comment: So why should we even use generators if they are the same? thats where i am confused!

Comment: They are *not* the same, but the defintions *look* similar. The function creates a list of all the requested Fibonacci numbers before returning it. The generator function creates a generator that will only compute each number as it is actually requested while iterating over it.

Comment: so they are void functions in c++ but with the capability of saving results as if they were passed by reference right?

Comment: Not quite, assuming by "void function" you mean a function that doesn't return a value. `fibonacci` still returns a value, but that value is something very similar to a coroutine, which is like a function but more general, in that you can suspend its execution and resume it later, rather than having to exit and restart.